# Can't log into the backend after switching domain

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I switched the server and the domain for a website. The frontend works, same for the install tool.
But now each time I try to connect into the backend I have this error "Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function" and I'm instantly redirected to the login page

[image: typeerror typo3 backend]

[image: typeerror typo3 backend]

I can't find anything about this error, it's a problem with the cookie? I missed a config?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the parameter [BE][lockIP] need to be set to 0 (no security check for IP). At least for my configuration it works. 
(using VPN + proxy to access the preprod website + some specific hosting conf)